# react-beautiful-dnd - Invariant failed: Cannot find droppable entry with id

Tags: reactjs, list, drag-and-drop, multiple-columns, react-beautiful-dnd

I was following along with a react-beautiful-dnd [tutorial](https://egghead.io/lessons/react-conditionally-allow-movement-using-react-beautiful-dnd-draggable-and-droppable-props) that uses react component classes instead of hooks. I was writing an equivalent program with modern react syntax when I came across this error. [Invariant failed: Cannot find droppable entry with id [column-1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJJV0.png). I was trying to dynamically update a variable that stores the origin column index to prevent the user from dragging a task to an earlier column. The error occurred when I attempted to use a useState hook inside of an onDragStart function. I have created a [codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-beautiful-dnd-invariant-error-example-31jvw?file=/src/App.js) showing the problem and would be very thankful for any help.

Answer (score 22):

just remove React.strictMode tag on your index.jsx/index.tsx file

Comment: Is there no other way?

Comment: Do you have any idea, why React.StrictMode makes beatiful-dnd unusable?

Comment: Why is that? @senko

Answer (score 12):

Instead of importing the "Dropable" form from "react-beautiful-dnd", you can use this custom component as a replacement:

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Droppable, DroppableProps } from "react-beautiful-dnd";
export const StrictModeDroppable = ({ children, ...props }: DroppableProps) => {
  const [enabled, setEnabled] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    const animation = requestAnimationFrame(() => setEnabled(true));
    return () => {
      cancelAnimationFrame(animation);
      setEnabled(false);
    };
  }, []);
  if (!enabled) {
    return null;
  }
  return <Droppable {...props}>{children}</Droppable>;
};
```

Credit for the TypeScript version goes to [GiovanniACamacho](https://github.com/GiovanniACamacho) and [Meligy](https://github.com/Meligy) on GitHub.

Comment: You deserve more upvotes

Comment: genius! Thanks for providing this workaround!

Answer (score 7):

Try removing React's strict mode.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

Just replace **[react-beautiful-dnd](https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd)** with **[@hello-pangea/dnd](https://github.com/hello-pangea/dnd)**. It is a 1:1 replacement (as it is a fork of react-beautiful-dnd) and maintenance seems to bee quite a bit better than the one provided by Atlassian. Also with more than 1K stars it's quite popular already and easy to replace.

Just replace all imports from `react-beautiful-dnd` with `@hello-pangea/dnd` and run any of those commands:

```
# npm
npm install @hello-pangea/dnd --save

# pnpm
pnpm add @hello-pangea/dnd

# yarn
yarn add @hello-pangea/dnd
```

Comment: Thanks.. This deserves an upvote - resolved it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove React.StrictMode in index.js/ index.ts
I have try and it fix my issue

Answer (score 0):

For me changing the way I render the root/App from:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

to this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

seemed to do the trick. Not sure if an issue with newer version of React.

Answer (score 0):

with Droppable, mention type='group' to solve this problem

```
    <Droppable
        droppableId={"droppable"}
        type="group">
       {provided=>(
           )}
    </Droppable>
```